# What is the quickest way to get all hash tags from Twitter feed in PHP?

Tags: php

This might be simple question, but what is the quickest (less execution time) to find certain words in text.

```
Example: search for all words with hash tag in beginning  of the word

Input:    #google bought #zagat today    
Output:   google zagat
```

Answer (score 4):

```
/#[^ ]+/
```

You can use `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all ( '/#[^ ]+/' , $subject, $matches );
```

Comment: can you please explain what `[^ ]` means?

Comment: Sure. The OP said 'less execution time'. `preg_match` surely needs some buffers and/or other data structures (parsing is a complex task), and more, when it populates the resulting array, it has to allocate more buffers, one for each result, and the array itself. If the results are 1000, then 1000 buffers. Instead, piping each result in a single string, involves no data structures.

Comment: hate to break it to u gd1 but twitter statuses rarely have 1000 hashtags lol

Answer (score 1):

Split the string by the `#` character, and then split by a space. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

This is a quick solution I threw together:

```
  $str = '#google bought #zagat today';

  $a = explode('#', $str);

  foreach ($a as $key=>$value) {
    if($a != "") {
      $b = explode(' ', $value);
      echo $b[0] . " ";
    }
  }

 // output: google zagat
```

Another solution, uses explode once:

```
  $str = '#google bought #zagat today';

  foreach (explode(' ', $str) as $key=>$value) {    
    if(substr($value, 0, 1) == '#')
      echo str_replace('#', '', $value) . " ";          
  } 

 // output: google zagat
```

Comment: the above mentioned solution doesnt work for multiline values (if it doesnt end with space but with newline).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple code:

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match_all(
  '/#([^\s]+)/i',
  'text#tag ' . PHP_EOL . '#tag5 #tagščřý continue',
  $matches
);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

will output

```
array
  0 => string 'tag' (length=3)
  1 => string 'tag5' (length=4)
  2 => string 'tagščřý' (length=11)
```

Regular match everything after hash (including numbers and unicode chars). It's case insensitive `/i`.

If you require space before - just add `\s` to regular expression `'/\s#([^\s]+)/i'` output will be:

```
array
  0 => string 'tag5' (length=4)
  1 => string 'tagščřý' (length=11)
```